# Meaning of "hooked for life"

Tags: meaning

I was reading a book, the author described the scenery of a certain place, and then said: "You're hooked for life." The search engine told me it means, you have been fascinated by this scenery all your life, "for life" represents the duration of the action of fascination.

My questions are:

1. Can this sentence only be used after the previous sentence describes the charm of something?
2. If I want to express people's obsession with life itself, can I use "hooked on life"?

Your reply will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you're "hooked for life", it means you've form a bond/attraction/ attachment that will never leave you. Once you've seen the scenery, you'll never let go your attachment to or love of it.

Answer (score 2):

When you're "hooked for life", it means you've formed a bond/attraction/ attachment that will never leave you. Once you've seen the scenery in question, you'll never let go your attachment to or love for it.

Cambridge: [hooked for life](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hooked)

Comment: It's worth noting that one of the meanings is "unable to stop taking a drug", although it's often used for other simpler pleasures. So it doesn't necessarily imply an unpleasant or dangerous addiction, but sometimes there may be that meaning.